# Creating hyper link in lwc using LDS

Tags: lightning-web-components

need to convert the below output field to a hyperlink, I tried to surround it with **a** tag but it didn't work, could someone please confirm if an output field can also be a hyper link

```
<lightning-record-view-form record-id={proposalData} object-api-name="Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c" density="compact">
    <lightning-output-field id="Approval_Stage" field-name="Apttus_Proposal__Approval_Stage__c"
                    variant="label-hidden">
</lightning-record-view-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try out this component.

```html
 <template>
 <p><lightning-formatted-url value="my/path" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
 <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://my/path" tooltip="Go to https://my/path" label="My Cool Website" target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
 <p><lightning-formatted-url value="ftp://my/path" tooltip="Go to ftp://my/path" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
 <p><lightning-formatted-url value="http://my/path" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
 <p><lightning-formatted-url value="/my/path" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
 <p><lightning-formatted-url value=".my/path" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
</template>


[1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-url/example
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my question and formatted URL is not working, please suggest