# api decorator undefined when using in js

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am passing the productConfigId to apex and getting result as expected and also I am using this id in HTML and it is working expected but when I use it in goToSubjectCount it results undefined instead of the ID, please suggest.

```
export default class APTPS_Configure_Visit_Schedule_LWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {


    @api productConfigId;
    @api configRequestId;

    @track imageUrl = apptusLogo;
    @track proposalData;
    @track goToSubjectCount='/apex/APTPS_Configure_Subject_Counts?id=' + this.productConfigId + '&configRequestId=' + this.configRequestId + '';
    @track goToMapSupplyQuantity = '/apex/APTPS_Configure_Subject_Counts?id=' + this.productConfigId + '&configRequestId=' + this.configRequestId + '';


    @wire(proposalDetails, { productConfigId: '$productConfigId' })
    proposalDetail({data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.proposalData = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `productConfigId` value is set by a parent of your component. So the problem is that when you instantiate your `goToSubjectCount` variable, the `productConfigId` value is not arealdy set by its parent.

For your case, the only solution I see would be to overwrite the setter of the `productConfigId` variable. By overwriting the setter, you could set the new value of your `goToSujbectCount` variable every time the value is changed. The same applies to the `configRequestId` variable. Here's the code to implement this solution:

```
@track goToSubjectCount;

_productConfigId;
_configRequestId;

@api
get productConfigId(){
    return this._productConfigId;
}
set productConfigId(value){
    this._productConfigId = value;
    setGoToSubjectCount();
} 

@api
get configRequestId(){
    return this._configRequestId;
}
set configRequestId(value){
    this._configRequestId = value;
    this.setGoToSubjectCount();
}

setGoToSubjectCount(){
    this.goToSubjectCount ='/apex/APTPS_Configure_Subject_Counts?id=' + this._productConfigId + '&configRequestId=' + this._configRequestId + '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Martin but I am getting an error setGoToSubjectCount() is not defined

Comment: Did you copy the whole code with the function at the end?

Comment: You are awesome, thank you so much I changed setGoToSubjectCount(); to this.this.setGoToSubjectCount(); and it is working as expected, Could you please look into my other LWC questions?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283302/creating-hyper-link-in-lwc-using-lds

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283201/navigation-is-not-working-in-lwc

Comment: Thank you in advance for the rest of the questions

Comment: Yes I totally forgot the this before calling the method. I updated my code. I will have a look into the rest of the questions.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin